# How fast SQOOP can transfer from RDBMS to Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

Can someone tell me, how fast SQOOP can transfer 2 billion record in one time. And i know it must be fast because sqoop run in parallel, where some inputs will be produced also some file Output on Hadoop. but I want to know the details of the speed MapReduce transfer amount of 2 billion records in one time.

Comment: It depends upon number of mappers assigned for that job. So for example , if standalone(single) process taking 4 minutes to transfer the data, Sqoop with 4 mappers will take less than 1 min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the points responsible for faster transfer of data from RDBMS to Hadoop.

- **Number of Mappers:**

  Increasing the number of mappers will increase your speed because it divides the task in parts and performs import parallelly.
- **Balanced load on Mappers:**

  You need to split on a column that is uniform *(prefer integer)*. It will give balanced load to all the mappers and transfer is faster.
- **Number of connection from RDBMS:**

  You can not just blindly increase the number of mappers *(like 100 or more)*. Your RDBMS should allow these concurrent connections otherwise it will be a bottleneck from RDBMS side.
- **Use `--Direct` mode:**

  If direct connector is provided by sqoop for a particular RDBMS, you should use it. It will make transfer faster.

---

In a nutshell, sqoop is faster enough to tranfer billions of record just keep these points in your mind while writing import command.

Comment: You did't point out the network and RDMS itself as limiting factors, we(this is a real life example) have a remote cluster and it has only limited bandwidth, as a result it caps the maximum transfer speed and nothing of what you pointed out is going to help with that. RDMS also matters, is it a single node system or distributed one, how heavily is it loaded?

Comment: @MaxNevermind I agree with you. you can another answer mentioning other points..:)